# QlikSense Set Analysis - Sum Less than HH:MM Format

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression, set-analysis

I am trying to calculate a sum where certain Time criteria are met. My date column STime is stored in a HH:MM format (13:15, 17:25, etc.).

I have a variable, vCurrentTime, in the same format, calculated as:

```
TIME(NOW(), 'HH:MM')
```

Here is what my data looks like:

```
Person     STime   Points
Alex       15:00     10
Brandon    11:50     8
Carlos     16:04     12
Denise     13:25     4
Elise      16:09     30
Felicia    17:50     31
George     18:00     35
```

I'd like to sum the Points column in all instances where STime is less than vCurrentTime, or at the time of posting this question, about 14:45.

Only 2 rows meet that criteria (Brandon and Denise), so my desired output would be 12 (4+8).

The set analysis I'm using below has been returning 0:

```
SUM({$<STime = {"<=$(=$(vCurrentTime))"}>}Points)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from the screenshot below there is difference in the time based on the format:

[image: Time]

- `TIME(NOW(), 'hh:mm')` - returns the correct system time (20:04)
- `TIME(NOW(), 'HH:MM')` - returns the correct hour but the minutes are wrong.

The difference between `mm` and `MM` is that `mm` is describing the minutes of the hour and `MM` is the month of the year (thats why the "minutes" are 12 aka December)

Once this is in place the expression seems to work ok in my case

- left table - Raw data view (ive added one extra record for `Person = TEST)
- middle table - `Person` as dimension and copy/paste the expression that is in the question. As you can see `TEST` record is not present because its `STime` is `21:00` and the current time is `20:04`
- right table - `sum(Points)` without any set analysis
- bottom - the corrected variable view

[image: Data]

Comment: good catch, I was actually using hh:mm after all, and naively thought there was no difference. The expression works in a table for me like it looks like it does for you as well, but not when I try to plot a singular sum on a kpi card (gives 0)

Comment: Its working for me in a text box (QV) and KPI Object (QS)